# Handling regular form posts (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) with servant

Tags: forms, haskell, post, servant

How can I handle regular form POSTs with Servant? In particular, given an HTML form like

```
<form action="/check" method="post">
  Solution:
  <input name="code" type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and

```
data CheckResult = Correct | Wrong

instance ToHtml CheckResult
    ...

checkCode :: Text -> Handler CheckResult
checkCode code = if code == "secret" then Correct else Wrong
```

how do I string things together?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just wanted to add an answer for a recent version of Servant, because I had to google various things in order to assemble a complete, working version of form handling.

The above answer works well for earlier versions of Servant, but I got stuck using forms when upgrading to Servant 0.9.

Here's how I did it.

First of all, they switched from a custom Form implementation to the one in [http-api-data](https://github.com/fizruk/http-api-data), so you need that in your cabal file:

*some-project.cabal*

```
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                     , aeson
                     , blaze-html
                     , http-api-data
```

Next, you can declare a form, like above, but you can use `GHC.Generics` to automatically derive a `FromForm` instance:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}

module Html.Contact where

import           GHC.Generics
import           Servant
import           Web.FormUrlEncoded          (FromForm)

data ContactForm = ContactForm
 { cname    :: !T.Text
 , cemail   :: !T.Text
 , cmessage :: !T.Text
 } deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)

instance FromForm ContactForm
```

After that, you can use the regular `FormUrlEncoded` ContentType from Servant in your endpoint:

```
type ContactApi = "contact" :> ReqBody '[FormUrlEncoded] ContactForm
                                   :> Post '[HTML] Html
```

**Almost forgot: How to render the thing**

You will also need a page, probably, where you are displaying your form? Well, the "name" attributes have to match the fields in your form (here's how I did it, using `Blaze`):

```
contactForm :: H.Html
contactForm = H.section ! A.id "contact" ! A.class_ "container contact-us u-full-width u-max-full-width" $
  H.div ! A.class_ "row" $ do
    H.div ! A.class_ "eight columns contact-us-form" $
      H.form ! A.method "post" ! A.action "/contact" $ do
        H.div ! A.class_ "row" $ do
          H.div ! A.class_ "six columns" $
            H.input ! A.class_ "u-full-width" ! A.type_ "text" ! A.name "cname" ! A.placeholder "Name" ! A.id "nameInput"
          H.div ! A.class_ "six columns" $
            H.input ! A.class_ "u-full-width" ! A.type_ "text" !  A.name "cemail" ! A.placeholder "Email" ! A.id "emailInput"
        H.textarea ! A.class_ "u-full-width" ! A.name "cmessage" ! A.placeholder "Message" ! A.id "messageInput" $ ""
        H.input ! A.class_ "button u-pull-right" ! A.type_ "submit" !  A.value "Send"
```

Answer (score 4):

Servant supports this via the data type [FormUrlEncoded](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.2/servant-0.8.1/Servant-API-ContentTypes.html#t:FormUrlEncoded), and the class [FromFormUrlEncoded](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.2/servant-0.8.1/Servant-API-ContentTypes.html#t:FromFormUrlEncoded) (renamed to `FromForm` in Servant 0.9).

First we define a data type for the form data, and rewrite our handler to accept that.

```
data CheckRequest = CheckRequest { code :: Text }

checkCode :: CheckRequest -> Handler CheckResult
checkCode (CheckRequest code) = if code == "secret" then Correct else Wrong
```

Then we specify a POST body of type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

```
type API = "check"
         :> ReqBody '[FormUrlEncoded] CheckRequest
         :> Post '[HTML] CheckResult
```

Now all that's required is to make `CheckRequest` an instance of `FromFormUrlEncoded`.

```
instance FromFormUrlEncoded CheckRequest where
  --fromFormUrlEncoded :: [(Text, Text)] -> Either String CheckRequest
  fromFormUrlEncoded [("code", c)] = Right (CheckRequest c)
  fromFormUrlEncoded _             = Left "expected a single field `code`"
```